# How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML_LOAD(); function

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I have an XML file which looks like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<resultset statement="YOUR SQL STATEMENTS TO GENERATE THIS XML FILE" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="personal_number">539</field>
    <field name="firstname">Name</field>
    <field name="lastname">Surname</field>
    <field name="email">email.domain.com</field>
    <field name="start_time">2011-04-02 13:30:00</field>
    <field name="end_time">2011-04-02 18:15:00</field>
    <field name="employee_category">1,2,4,5,22,37,38,39,41,43,44</field>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field name="personal_number">539</field>
    <field name="firstname">Name</field>
    <field name="lastname">Surname</field>
    <field name="email">email.domain.com</field>
    <field name="start_time">2011-04-02 13:30:00</field>
    <field name="end_time">2011-04-02 18:15:00</field>
    <field name="employee_category">1,2,4,5,22,37,38,39,41,43,44</field>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field name="personal_number">539</field>
    <field name="firstname">Name</field>
    <field name="lastname">Surname</field>
    <field name="email">email.domain.com</field>
    <field name="start_time">2011-04-02 13:30:00</field>
    <field name="end_time">2011-04-02 18:15:00</field>
    <field name="employee_category">1,2,4,5,22,37,38,39,41,43,44</field>
  </row>
```

I am trying to import it in MySQL using SQL statement :

```
use databasename;
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' INTO TABLE my_tablename;
```

The table my_tablename has the following fields :

```
id (auto increment id)
personal_number(varchar)
firstname(varchar) 
lastname(varchar)
email(varchar) 
start_time(varchar)
end_time(varchar)
employee_category(varchar)
```

I get error : 
Error Code: 1136
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I am using MySQL 5.1.56

I assume this error occurs because the database table has field id, which is not present in the XML file. How is it possible to import this XML file using MySQL queries of built in functions such that it skips id column during the import and relies on the auto increment function for the id column?
Is there some smarter way of handling XML file imports im MySQL?
Maybe there is better statement which allows to specify column mapping?

Thank you!

Comment: for mysql 5.1 read on this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html "User Comments" section

Answer (score 50, accepted):

you can specify fields like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE my_tablename(personal_number, firstname, ...);
```

Answer (score 8):

Since ID is auto increment, you can also specify ID=NULL as,

> LOAD  XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' INTO TABLE my_tablename SET ID=NULL;