# insert Xml file data into MySQL table

Tags: java, xml, database

I want to insert the Xml file data into MySQL table ,,  by choosing which  column to insert into ,, using Java How will this be done ?

Comment: Do you want to add the xml document in its entirety into the table or do you want to parse and insert the element contents to the table?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the format of your XML file. If your XML file is a direct export from the MySQL file, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function).

If your XML is in some other format, then I would probably be using JAXB to parse XML into POJO, then write some logic to map the POJO into the database table.