# Import XML with attributes into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a large (~30Mb) XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<LIC Version="2.0" Title="Products">
    <Item>
        <Field Name="Filename">/root/_DOWNLOAD/Bird.txt</Field>
        <Field Name="Read_By">Lisa Hannigan</Field>
        <Field Name="Posit">Passenger</Field>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Field Name="Filename">D:\03\Strypers.pdf</Field>
        <Field Name="Read_By">Stryper</Field>
        <Field Name="Intensity">2</Field>
        <Field Name="IMG">78</Field>
        <Field Name="Rotate">0</Field>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Field Name="Filename">D:\Afriu.txt</Field>
        <Field Name="Read_By">Africano</Field>
        <Field Name="Posit">Canto Africano vol.1</Field>
        <Field Name="File_Resource">mp3</Field>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Field Name="Filename">D:\_VARIOUS\Knots.pdf</Field>
        <Field Name="Date">40624</Field>
    </Item>
    ...
</LIC>
```

I want to import this xml into mysql database, with a php script. I've used SIMPLEXML and xpath:

```
    $url = 'FILE.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $result = $xml->xpath("//Field[@Name]");
foreach { ... }
```

What do i need? What is the correct "foreach" to create an array to use for mysql sql?
Notes that every row (identify by "Item") is not same (not have the same "Field Name").
Is it correct to use simplexml for larger file?
Thank you for help!

*update*

This is an example to use "foreach", i tried:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("//Field[@Name]");    
foreach($result as $key => $value)  {
    echo $value['Name']."=".$value.",";
 }
```

Now I want to find out how to create the string to insert in mysql

Comment: I think you may need to explain your MySQL table structure if you said every `Item` may have different `Field.Name`...

Comment: You can use XPath to read each item, and then use XPath to read each field based on it's name value, i.e. `$item->xpath("Field[@Name='Read_By']")` of which you can then get the value of that field.

Comment: @Passerby : mySQL table was create with all field! From my example:
`CREATE TABLE 'custom' (
 `IDm` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Filename` TEXT,
 `Read_By` varchar(240),
 `Posit` varchar(255),
 `Intensity` varchar(240),
 `IMG` TEXT,
 `Rotate` varchar(240),
 `File_Resource` varchar(240),
 `Date` varchar(240),`
and so on..

Comment: See as well: [How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML_LOAD(); function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5491056/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer my question.

```
<?php
    $url = 'FILEXML';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);    
$i = 1;
  foreach($xml->xpath("/LIC/Item") as $docs)
  {
        foreach($docs->Field as $field) 
        {
            $resultstr[] = $field["Name"];
        }
    $sql_head = headquote($resultstr);
    $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO table_name (";
    $sql_dec = ") VALUE (";
    unset($resultstr);
    $fresult = (array)$docs;
    $fvalue = array_pop($fresult);
    $sql_val = numking($fvalue);
    $sql_end = ");";
    $query_to_use_for_mysql = ($sql_ins.$sql_head.$sql_dec.$sql_val.$sql_end);

    unset($fresult);
    unset($fvalue);
 }
 ?>
```

And add this two functions:

```
<?php
    function headquote($hdarray) {
            $hdata   = array();
            foreach ( $hdarray as $hdval ) {
                #       Use backticks instead quotes!
            $hdata[] = "`$hdval`";
              }
        $hdarray = implode($hdata, ',');
        return $hdarray;
     }
    function numking($input) {
            $data   = array();
            foreach ( $input as $value ) {
            $data[] = is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'".mysql_escape_string($value)."'";
             }
            $input = implode($data, ',');
            return $input;
      }
?>
```

Thanks to all for help!

Answer (score 3):

First create a table that matches all possible fields as columns. Then you can load it by a  [`LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE` query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml'
  INTO TABLE person
  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Item>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this query and the result is a table with all fields = NULL

Comment: @kingmo: Watch out that you properly align the attribute names with your column names. Read the manual link carefully.

Comment: CAn I use this with php - I cannot make it happen via php, even though   I can import the file into the database with direct access via terminal, I just want to import it via web

Comment: Yes you can do it by php, provided the user you are using to access database in php has FILE privilege.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'FILE.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i=0;$i<count($xml->Item);$i++)
{
   print_r($xml->Item[$i]);
 }
```