# Insert XML Data to MySQL Table Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to insert xml data to my sql but it is not inserting. how to write the foreach(xml->) for this type of xml.the xml is generated dynamically in this structure.this is a sample xml in this format

```
<?php
$xmlData =<<< END
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customer>
<id>1</id>
<name>Oluwafemi</name>
<address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>
<list>
<contact>56689</contact>
<telephone>5889745</telephone>
</list>
<offer>congrats</offer>
</Customer>
END;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("ERROR: Cannot create SimpleXML object");
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Customers") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

foreach ($xml->Customer as $Customer) {
$id = $Customer->id;
echo "$id";
$name =  $Customer->name;
$address = $Customer->address;

$sql = "INSERT INTO customerdata (id, name, address ) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$address')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connection) . " (query was $sql)");
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Hint: The mysql commandline tool can import most XML files directly. See as well [How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML_LOAD(); function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5491056/367456)

Comment: Hntt#2: `$xml` in your example represents the document `<Customer>` element already. This mistake is common amongst new SimpleXML users. In your case you just don't need to foreach here as it's only a single customer row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your XML document, encapsulate the document with this tag: 
 `<Customers> ... </Customers>`

So the beginning portion of your code should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
$sXmlString =<<< END
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Oluwafemi</name>
    <address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
END;
```

EDIT: OP is unable to edit the XML provided, I assume it is structured where new customers would be added in with additional id, name, address entities. Here is the updated code for OP:

```
<?php
$xmlData =<<< END
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customer>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Oluwafemi</name>
  <address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Rob</name>
  <address> 123 Longhorn </address>
</Customer>
END;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("ERROR: Cannot create SimpleXML object");
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Customers") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

/* Assumes that the number of IDs = number of customers */
$size = sizeOf($xml->id);
$i = 0; //index

/* Add each customer to the database, See how we reference it as    $xml->ENTITY[INDEX] */
while($i != $size) 
{
    //echo $xml->id[$i]; //Test
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customerdata (id, name, address ) VALUES ('$xml->id[$i]', '$xml->name[$i]', '$xml->address[$i]')";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connection) . " (query was $sql)");

    $i++; //increment index
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

I also added in an additional customer id with data. You can remove that and the code will still work fine.

Comment: Hi RobMullins,
the xml is generated dynamically. any help for  that xml

Comment: You should really structure your XML better. Since you cannot, I will update the answer...

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Thanku Rob Mullins. got the expected output what i want.
thanku so much

Comment: if there is one more element inside how can we get the data.

Comment: Additional entities would be referenced within the while loop, as `$xml->ENTITY[$i]` So if you had a phone-number field, it would be: `$xml->phone[$i]`
Call `print_r($xml)` before the while loop so you can better understand the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple customers...

```
$sXmlString =<<< END
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Content>
<Customer>
<id>1</id>
<name>Oluwafemi</name>
<address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<id>2</id>
<name>Oluwafemi2</name>
<address>Cresent Drive 2, TX</address>
</Customer>
</Content>
END;

$oXml       = simplexml_load_string($sXmlString);
$sJson      = json_encode( $oXml );
$aContent   = json_decode( $sJson, TRUE );
$aCustomers = $aContent[ 'Customer' ];
var_dump( $aCustomers );
$iCountCustomers = count( $aCustomers );
for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountCustomers; ++$i )
{
    $sId      = $aCustomers[ $i ][ 'id' ];
    $sName    = $aCustomers[ $i ][ 'name' ];
    $sAddress = $aCustomers[ $i ][ 'address' ];
    var_dump( $sId );
    var_dump( $sName );
    var_dump( $sAddress );
}
```