# Insert into database from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to Insert data from XML to MySql.

So far i have written this:
?php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "rootuser";
$dbname = "my_data";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$string = file_get_contents('rss.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo 'All Values of a Group: -';
foreach($xml->system->system as $item){
    echo $item->MY_Name.' - ';
    echo $item->Version.' - ';
    echo '<br/>';
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO customer_data_table (My_Name, Version ) VALUES (". $item->My_Name.", '". $item->Version."')" );
}
?
```

**Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: have you tried anything ??

Comment: have you tried ? please show your code

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161722/parsing-xml-data-using-php-to-put-into-mysql-database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057366/insert-xml-data-to-mysql-table-using-php

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [https://stackoverflow.com/help].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML data using php to put into mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161722/parsing-xml-data-using-php-to-put-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Code added. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

In PHP use xml parser to get the values from the XML. Here is the code

```
$xml = '<system>
<Name>new</Name>
<Month>Feb</Month>
</system>';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(new SimpleXMLElement($xml));
```

Here you can get all the values from XML tag and you can insert into Database.