# How to load and extract xml file data into phpmyadmin database?

Tags: xml, import, phpmyadmin

I have an xml file with multiple *nodes* *sub-nodes* and *attributes* and I want to load its data into **phpmyadmin database**.

Is it necessary to first create *tables* before loading data?

What is the simplest way to carry out this task?

Any hep is highly appreciated. Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML\_LOAD(); function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function)