# SQL Insert From XML Into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using MS-SQL. I have `xml` which has structure `survey, section, rows, cells`. I want to import the `values` from `nodes` into three `tables` which are related `dbo.sections, dbo.rows, dbo.cells`. For this purpose I have to iterate over this `xml`. First `insert` the `section` and get the `scode_indentity()` and use it for the insert for `child row` as `FK` to `inserted` section. Then get `cell` inside the `inserted row` and to `insert` it with `FK` `scope_indentity()` `(id from the inserted parent row node)`. What is the `best practice` in this situation `to map nodes parent to child`, insert and get `scope_indentity()` and `pass it` to child values for the insert statement ?

**Tables DESCRIPTION:**

```
dbo.sections

dbo.rows -> FK to sections

dbo.cells -> FK to rows
```

**XML DESCRIPTION:**

```
<survey S_VALUE1="45" S_VALUE2="1" S_VALUE3="1">
    <section SE_VALUE1="34" SE_VALUE2="1855436" SE_VALUE3="False">
        <row R_VALUE1="29" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="28" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="29" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="30" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
        <row R_VALUE1="30" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="31" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="32" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="33" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
        <row R_VALUE1="31" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="34" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="35" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="36" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
    </section>
    <section SE_VALUE1="35" SE_VALUE2="1855436" SE_VALUE3="False">
        <row R_VALUE1="32" R_VALUE2="7444255"/>
        <row R_VALUE1="33" R_VALUE2="7444255"/>
        <row R_VALUE1="34" R_VALUE2="7444255"/>
    </section>
</survey>
```

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML\_LOAD(); function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp
GO

DECLARE @x XML = '
<survey S_VALUE1="45" S_VALUE2="1" S_VALUE3="1">
    <section SE_VALUE1="34" SE_VALUE2="1855436" SE_VALUE3="False">
        <row R_VALUE1="29" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="28" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="29" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="30" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
        <row R_VALUE1="30" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="31" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="32" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="33" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
        <row R_VALUE1="31" R_VALUE2="7444255">
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="34" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="35" C_VALUE3="1" />
            <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" C_VALUE2="36" C_VALUE3="1" />
        </row>
    </section>
    <section SE_VALUE1="35" SE_VALUE2="1855436" SE_VALUE3="False">
        <row R_VALUE1="32" R_VALUE2="7444255" />
        <row R_VALUE1="33" R_VALUE2="7444255" />
        <row R_VALUE1="34" R_VALUE2="7444255" />
    </section>
</survey>'

SELECT
      SE_VALUE1 = t.c.value('@SE_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , SE_VALUE2 = t.c.value('@SE_VALUE2', 'INT')
    , SE_VALUE3 = t.c.value('@SE_VALUE3', 'BIT')
    , R_VALUE1 = t2.c2.value('@R_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , R_VALUE2 = t2.c2.value('@R_VALUE2', 'INT')
    , C_VALUE1 = t3.c3.value('@C_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , C_VALUE2 = t3.c3.value('@C_VALUE2', 'INT')
    , C_VALUE3 = t3.c3.value('@C_VALUE3', 'BIT')
INTO #temp
FROM @x.nodes('survey/section') t(c)
OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('row') t2(c2)
OUTER APPLY t2.c2.nodes('cell') t3(c3)

INSERT INTO tbl1...
SELECT DISTINCT SE_VALUE1, SE_VALUE2, SE_VALUE3
FROM #temp

INSERT INTO tbl2...
SELECT DISTINCT R_VALUE1, R_VALUE2
FROM #temp t1
JOIN tbl1 t2 ON t1.SE_VALUE1 = t2.SE_VALUE1
WHERE t1.R_VALUE1 IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO tbl3...
SELECT DISTINCT C_VALUE1, C_VALUE2, C_VALUE3
FROM #temp t1
JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.R_VALUE1 = t2.R_VALUE1
WHERE t1.C_VALUE1 IS NOT NULL
```

Update:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '
<section SE_VALUE1="34">
    <row R_VALUE1="29">
        <cell C_VALUE1="43830582" />
    </row>
    <row R_VALUE1="30" R_VALUE2="7444255" />
</section>
<section SE_VALUE1="35" />'

SELECT
      SE_VALUE1 = t.c.value('@SE_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , R_VALUE1 = t2.c2.value('@R_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , C_VALUE1 = t3.c3.value('@C_VALUE1', 'INT')
FROM @x.nodes('section') t(c)
OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('row') t2(c2)
OUTER APPLY t2.c2.nodes('cell') t3(c3)

SELECT
      SE_VALUE1 = t.c.value('@SE_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , R_VALUE1 = t2.c2.value('@R_VALUE1', 'INT')
    , C_VALUE1 = t3.c3.value('@C_VALUE1', 'INT')
FROM @x.nodes('section') t(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('row') t2(c2)
CROSS APPLY t2.c2.nodes('cell') t3(c3)
```

Output:

```
SE_VALUE1   R_VALUE1    C_VALUE1
----------- ----------- -----------
34          29          43830582
34          30          NULL
35          NULL        NULL

SE_VALUE1   R_VALUE1    C_VALUE1
----------- ----------- -----------
34          29          43830582
```

Comment: You were faster than me :-) Like it!

Comment: Ok thank you, but one question. Why do you use outer apply here ?

Comment: @TheChampp because row and cell elements may be missing. I'll add an example

Comment: Yes I understand now. When I insert section I need the scope_indentity() to play role as FK when I insert row for this section. Can you advise me some approach ? Should I make it with cursor or ?

Comment: For your tables `PK` is a `INT IDENTITY`?

Comment: Yes. PK is a INT IDENTITY. But I want for example when Section is inserted  then I should get the inserted section ID(PK). Because row must know to which FK_SECTION belongs to in the insert statement of the row. The same for cell and row. Cell must know to which ROW_ID belongs to.