# How to import custom xml to mysql

Tags: mysql, xml

How i can import a custom XML file into a MySQL?

My XML :

```
    <ObjectList>
    <Section Index="0" Name="MichaelCat">
        <Item Index="0" Slot="0" FirstNmae="Example1" LastName="Example2" Age="30"  />
        <Item Index="1" Slot="0" FirstNmae="Example1.2" LastName="Example2.1" Age="30"  />
    </Section>

    <Section Index="1" Name="MichaelCat2">
        <Item Index="0" Slot="0" FirstNmae="Example1" LastName="Example2" Age="30"  />
        <Item Index="1" Slot="0" FirstNmae="Example1.2" LastName="Example2.1" Age="30"  />
    </Section>
</ObjectList>
```

My DB Schema:

```
SectionName | Section | Index | Slot | FIrstName | LastName | Age
```

In SectionName need to be inserted `Section->Name`

In Section need to be inserted `Section->Index`

In Index need to be inserted `Section->Item->Index`

In Slot need to be inserted `Section->Item->Slot`

etc..

In MSSQL i use:

```
DECLARE @input XML = 'MY XML file'

select
  Name = XCol.value('../@Index','varchar(25)'),
  Cat = XCol.value('../@Name','varchar(25)'),
  [Index] = XCol.value('@Index','varchar(25)'),
  Slot = XCol.value('@Slot','varchar(25)')
from
  @input.nodes('/ItemList/Section/Item') AS test(XCol)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: When I Google `import custom XML to mySQL` I get a lot of results, is none of them useful? Can you elaborate why?

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function

Comment: in my mssql i use

`DECLARE @input XML = 'MY XML file'
select
  Name = XCol.value('../@Index','varchar(25)'),
  Cat = XCol.value('../@Name','varchar(25)'),
  [Index] = XCol.value('@Index','varchar(25)'),
  Slot = XCol.value('@Slot','varchar(25)')
from
  @input.nodes('/ItemList/Section/Item') AS test(XCol)`

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html). Seems pretty straightforward. In your case, maybe something like:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'some_file.xml'
INTO TABLE person
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<section>';
```