# How to import XML datas into Mysql table?

Tags: mysql, xml

Here is extract from XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-15'?>
<annonces>
    <annonce>
        <transac>V</transac>
        <type_bien>Maison</type_bien>
        <texte>hello world</texte>
        <p_tel>1210212</p_tel>
        <ann_prix>10</ann_prix>
        <ann_cp>2870</ann_cp>
        <ann_ville>CREPY</ann_ville>
        <ann_dept>2</ann_dept>
        <ann_surface>246</ann_surface>
        <ann_nbpieces>7</ann_nbpieces>
        <first_parution>1999-01-01</first_parution>
        <first_prix>0 &amp;euro;</first_prix>
    </annonce>
    <annonce>
    .....
</annonces>
```

1) is it possible to import that into mysql and create the table automatically ?

2) I tried with

```
LOAD XML INFILE '/datas/data.xml' INTO TABLE data;
```

adn got as result

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped:
>   0  Warnings: 0

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code , i think work for you

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/datas/data.xml'  INTO TABLE data(field1,field2,field3.field4...);
```

you can also use this code

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/datas/data.xml' INTO TABLE  data;
```

you need to sure that file path ok and table name and filed value same as your xml file and it is not possible using single query insert and create
use LOCAL before INFILE i think it will work

Comment: probably duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function?rq=1

Comment: i already used this code for my project so i write this and check this code also for more sure..

Comment: yah but answers look identical.

Comment: i found this solution from other side and more sure i also search and see it this link also so i also give up vote for this link. i gave two answer in this question and write his/her 1 question also

Comment: ohk then give upvote to my comment also :) happy coding @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2567989/shafiqul-islam

Comment: i will give you :) now its your turn ;P @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2567989/shafiqul-islam

Comment: thank you and i am sure my answer will work so i deserve it . ha ha ha