# Wordpress - add featured post with image using MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to add featured post with image in  Wordpress using MySQL. I want to do it only by MySQL(no php, only SQL). I tried to add post and then I added meta for the post too. Still, I cannot see featured post with image. Please advise where I am wrong? I have generated XML for records, please check and let me know where I am wrong.

Post Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<table_data name="wp_posts">
    <row>
        <field name="ID">62</field>
        <field name="post_author">1</field>
        <field name="post_date">2018-04-24 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_date_gmt">2018-04-24 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_content">&lt;img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-26" src="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/photos/testing2.jpg" alt="test" width="300" height="219"&gt;</field>
        <field name="post_title">Manual post</field>
        <field name="post_excerpt"></field>
        <field name="post_status">publish</field>
        <field name="comment_status">open</field>
        <field name="ping_status">open</field>
        <field name="post_password"></field>
        <field name="post_name"></field>
        <field name="to_ping"></field>
        <field name="pinged"></field>
        <field name="post_modified">0000-00-00 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_modified_gmt">0000-00-00 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_content_filtered"></field>
        <field name="post_parent">0</field>
        <field name="guid"></field>
        <field name="menu_order">0</field>
        <field name="post_type">post</field>
        <field name="post_mime_type"></field>
        <field name="comment_count">0</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="ID">63</field>
        <field name="post_author">1</field>
        <field name="post_date">2018-04-24 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_date_gmt">2018-04-24 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_content"></field>
        <field name="post_title">testing2</field>
        <field name="post_excerpt"></field>
        <field name="post_status">inherit</field>
        <field name="comment_status">closed</field>
        <field name="ping_status">open</field>
        <field name="post_password"></field>
        <field name="post_name">testing2</field>
        <field name="to_ping"></field>
        <field name="pinged"></field>
        <field name="post_modified">0000-00-00 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_modified_gmt">0000-00-00 00:00:00</field>
        <field name="post_content_filtered"></field>
        <field name="post_parent">62</field>
        <field name="guid">http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/photos/testing2.jpg</field>
        <field name="menu_order">0</field>
        <field name="post_type">attachment</field>
        <field name="post_mime_type">image/jpeg</field>
        <field name="comment_count">0</field>
    </row>
</table_data>
```

Meta of Post

```
<table_data name="wp_postmeta">
    <row>
        <field name="meta_id">211</field>
        <field name="post_id">62</field>
        <field name="meta_key">_thumbnail_id</field>
        <field name="meta_value">63</field>
    </row>
</table_data>
```

What is missing and how to add using MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import XML file into MySQL database table using XML\_LOAD(); function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function)

Comment: Not duplicate at all. Both are different. I am not asking about import. The XML data is content of records that I already have. I have nothing to do with Import or XML. I put XML data to make my content in MySQL readable, csv was also option but xml seems better